# Low Variables "Grid" Search Parameter... why am I failing?

Tags: search, grid, low-variables

I have a Low Variables Grid setup and I'm trying to just return the rows that match a value in a column, if it exists.

In the Low Variable setup, I have the column checked to be "Grid Column Searchable". And the grid column is a plain text field.

Is there any reason why my setup is returning all the rows, instead of just the one with "wa"?

```
{!-- Low Variables "Grid" Field. --}
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_states" search:gd_state="wa"}
  {lv_states:gd_state}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Alternatively, I tried to see if the low variables "Table" fieldtype or P&T Field Pack "List" would cover it but that isn't giving a result either.

Is searching those two field types possible?

```
{!-- Low Variables "List" Field. --}
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_states" search:item="wa"}
{item}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Thank you for any assistance,

Comment: Both the Table and the List types don't support search:column parameters, so that's as expected. Which version of both EE and LV are you using?

Comment: I was just looking into the bug history and it does look like the issue is related to the EE 2.73 / LV 2.61 setup I'm running. [link](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20034/grid-search-parameter-does-not-work-with-low-variables)

Comment: I won't be available right away to run the ugrades on this older install... any suggestions for an alternative approach? The suggestion in the bug report doesn't seem to apply, as the /system/expressionengine/models/grid_model.php file has the recommended code in it.

Comment: Not sure. I'd try and upgrade the software to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is related to a bug that existed with an older version of EE.

Details:

[Grid Search Parameter Does Not Work With Low Variables](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20034/grid-search-parameter-does-not-work-with-low-variables)

Thank you Low for your assistance.